# How do I track down an 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' on Core Data managed object

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I'm getting this error and have tried for several hours to diagnose the cause:

> [_NSCoreDataTaggedObjectID formulaName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd0000000000c0008

Thanks to [this article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1) I know that `_NSCoreDataTaggedObjectID` is the class name of the object I'm calling the method on (but that's not one of my classes) and `formulaName` is the method being called or, I guess in my case, it's the *property* being called.

I have a `UITableViewController` that displays LiftEvents based on a filter of `lift` that the user chooses:

```
extension LiftEvent {
    @NSManaged var date: Date
    @NSManaged var repetitions: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var uuid: String
    @NSManaged var weightLifted: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var weightUnit: String
    @NSManaged var formula: Formula
    @NSManaged var lift: Lift
}
```

Each LiftEvent has a Formula:

```
extension Formula {
    @NSManaged var formulaName: String
    @NSManaged var uuid: String
    @NSManaged var liftEvent: NSSet?
}
```

As each cell is being constructed with a liftEvent, I'm calling liftEvent.calculateOneRepMax() which needs the `liftEvent.formula.formulaName`:

```
 func calculateOneRepMax() -> Measurement<UnitMass> {
        var oneRepMax: Measurement<UnitMass>?
        let unit = liftWeight.unit
        let formulaName = formula.formulaName <-- Exception Breakpoint stops here
        switch formulaName {
        case "Baechle":
            let result = liftWeight * ( 1 + (0.033 * Double(truncating: repetitions)))
            oneRepMax = Measurement(value: result.value, unit: unit)

// the rest of the cases...
```

And at the exception breakpoint, there is a formula, but I get the unrecognized selector error when I try to `po self.formula.formulaName`:

> (lldb) po self.formula
>
> 0xd0000000000c000a `<x-coredata://CEE4B747-4119-4372-B5A8-368D0AF9FB69/Formula/p3>`
>
> (lldb) po self.formula.formulaName
>
> 2018-06-24 09:40:36.174149-0700 My 1 Rep Max[74577:5375031] -[_NSCoreDataTaggedObjectID formulaName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd0000000000c000a
>
> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: breakpoint 1.1.
>   The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

If I pick different `lift` filters **the UIViewController actually works most of the time**:

[image]

but other times I'll select the same `lift` filter that worked a minute ago, but now produces the crash.

I've been try to debug this for hours. I've set my own breakpoint all over the place and stepped through the code countless times. Does anybody have any suggestions about how else I can try to debug this?

Comment: check you are not crossing threads. If you are using an async api to populate your data you MUST spawn a context for that thread and merge.

Comment: Thanks, @WarrenBurton. How can I tell if I'm using an async api? In the stack trace at the exception breakpoint I see `Enqueued from com.apple.main-thread (Thread 1)`. All calls below it are dimmed out and the calls above it are the usual mix of dimmed and not dimmed. Is that any kind of clue about the threading?

Comment: [Turn on zombies](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/devcef23c572) and see what happens. If that doesn't help track it down, try turning on the address sanitizer.

Comment: @robmayoff - I've enabled zombies and when I use the Zombies profile template in Instruments I get a new Unexpectedly found nil will unwrapping an Optional error. Strangely, I don't get the unexpected nil error if I don't use Instruments. Is that normal?

Comment: Did you try enabling zombies in your scheme and running it directly under Xcode (not under Instruments)?

Comment: I did and I don't see any mentions of `zombie` in the console. Obviously I'm not very familiar with tracking down zombies so I've looked for tutorials and could only find very old ones.

Comment: What about the address sanitizer?

Comment: Yep, enabled it in my scheme as well, ran it, crashed, searched for `AddressSanitizer` in the console, got nothing.